# Why POST is routed to GET?

Tags: apex, rest-api, post, restresource

I have rest controller with GET, DELETE and POST. GET and DELETE work ok.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/test123')
global class TestRest {

    @HttpGet
    global static String getOperation(){
        return 'ok get';
    }

    @HttpDelete
    global static String deleteOperation(){
        return 'ok delete';
    }

    @HttpPost
    global static String postOperation() {
        return 'ok post';
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I send POST( using Postman ) to this endpoint I receive response for GET. This code works ok in another org. So, is there any setting, configuration, etc. that I should change?

Comment: can you copy and paste your request as curl? It's hard to answer without your request body

Comment: With token of test user(but there is no diffreance when I use administrator's token): curl -v -XPOST -H 'Authorization: Bearer 00D0O000000sgma!AQ0AQOu0xzsKA3oqaQpftaNkl5guLGauSv.kIfcQMN.utvRAK6l0Yr3Pl73Jsbt7pP4pgyvms79S563xHnO.KdUlI6WDNN0E' -H "Content-type: application/json" 'https://donkeymoney-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/services/apexrest/test123'

Comment: Idk, it works fine when I do post -- curl  -H 'Authorization: Bearer 00D0O000000sgma!AQ0AQOu0xzsKA3oqaQpftaNkl5guLGauSv.kIfcQMN.utvRAK6l0Yr3Pl73Jsbt7pP4pgyvms79S563xHnO.KdUlI6WDNN0E' -H "Content-type: application/json" 'https://na11.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/test123' -v -XPOST -H "Content-length:0"
Probably, there is some issue with postman or so

Comment: I've made request with curl and I got good response. After that I repeated request with Postman and surprisingly got a proper answer. To sum up, after 2 days debuging I've done nothing and it finally works. Thank you for your help

Comment: Please, change your password to the org ASAP -- cause with that token everyone in the world can access your org and break things there :)

Comment: No really :) As I said it is token of test user with diffrent permissions ;) and this is my dev org, so no client can complain about strange bugs :D and I'm pretty sure it has already expired, but in any case I will change that ;)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifying info. That's not what comments are for.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, accidentally I found this "bug". 
POST https://donkeymoney-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/services/apexrest/test123 returns GET, but POST https://donkeymoney-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/test123 is OK :) If you find similar bug in your own orgs I will report it to Salesforce